# How to place 7 subfigures properly aligned?

Tags: subfloats, minipage, alignment

as the title suggests, I am having some trouble aligning some subfigures inside the `figure` environment. So far, I have been modifying the `hspace{}` value in order to align the subfigures as I want. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{a4paper}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \hspace{-7em}
        \begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Pregunta 1]{
            \label{q1}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}
            }
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace{2em}
        \begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Pregunta 2]{
            \label{q2}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}
            }
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace{2em}
        \begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
        \subfloat[Pregunta 3]{
            \label{q3}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}
            }
        \end{minipage}\par\medskip
        \hspace{-7em}
        \begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Pregunta 4]{
            \label{q4}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}
            }
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace{2em}
        \begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Pregunta 5]{
            \label{q5}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}
            }
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace{2em}
        \begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
        \subfloat[Pregunta 6]{
            \label{q6}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}
            }
        \end{minipage}\par\medskip
        \centering
        \subfloat[Pregunta 7]{
            \label{q7}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}
            }
        \caption{Diagramas de barras del test post-experimento}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Next, there is an image of what I get. As you can see subfigures *b)* and *e)* are not aligned with *g)*. That is what I want to fix, but I don't know how, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Output of the MWE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason for going beyond the margins. Don't use `scale`, but set the width instead. And don't forget to avoid unwanted spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{a4paper}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering

\subfloat[Pregunta 1]{% <--- important
  \label{q1}% <--- important
  \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}% <--- important
}\hfill
\subfloat[Pregunta 2]{%
  \label{q2}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
}\hfill
\subfloat[Pregunta 3]{%
  \label{q3}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
}

\medskip

\subfloat[Pregunta 4]{%
  \label{q4}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
}\hfill
\subfloat[Pregunta 5]{%
  \label{q5}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
}\hfill
\subfloat[Pregunta 6]{%
  \label{q6}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
}

\medskip

\subfloat[Pregunta 7]{%
  \label{q7}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
}

\caption{Diagramas de barras del test post-experimento}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have eight subfloats, the last pair can be input as

```
\subfloat[Pregunta 7]{%
  \label{q7}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
}\hspace{0.02\textwidth}%
\subfloat[Pregunta 8]{%
  \label{q7}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
}
```

This is because the space between images in the first two rows is `0.02\textwidth`.

[image]

If you really want to go past the margins, you can do it in an automatic way by using `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` set to negative values and setting a parameter equal to the text width plus the “oversize”.

For the example I added the `showframe` option to `\geometry` in order to see the text block boundaries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{a4paper,showframe}

\newlength{\oversized}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\addtolength{\leftskip}{-3em}
\addtolength{\rightskip}{-3em}
\setlength{\oversized}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\oversized}{6em}

\subfloat[Pregunta 1]{%
  \label{q1}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.32\oversized]{example-image-a}%
}\hfill
\subfloat[Pregunta 2]{%
  \label{q2}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.32\oversized]{example-image-a}%
}\hfill
\subfloat[Pregunta 3]{%
  \label{q3}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.32\oversized]{example-image-a}%
}

\medskip

\subfloat[Pregunta 4]{%
  \label{q4}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.32\oversized]{example-image-a}%
}\hfill
\subfloat[Pregunta 5]{%
  \label{q5}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.32\oversized]{example-image-a}%
}\hfill
\subfloat[Pregunta 6]{%
  \label{q6}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.32\oversized]{example-image-a}%
}

\medskip

\subfloat[Pregunta 7]{%
  \label{q7}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.32\oversized]{example-image-a}%
}

\caption{Diagramas de barras del test post-experimento}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works and the code is very simple. Just one question, why are the `%` symbols important?

Comment: @anmomu Without them you get a space for each endline.

Comment: @anmomu I added a solution for “oversizing” the picture with little fuss.

Answer (score 3):

- `minipage`s are not needed
- text width can be locally enlarged by use of `\adjustwidth` macro, defined in the `changepage` package, however, in the first you need to ask yourself, is this is really needed
- determining image size with `width` in `Gin` keys enables simple possibility to make all image narrowed that can be fit in the `\textwidth` (see second example)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,  % in real document remove this option
            a4paper]{geometry}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} this is default encoding
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.32\linewidth} % <---
\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}   % <--- locally enlarge text width 
  \centering
  \subfloat[][Pregunta 1    \label{q1}]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][Pregunta 2    \label{q2}]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][Pregunta 3    \label{q2}]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}
  
\medskip
  \subfloat[][Pregunta 4    \label{q4}]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][Pregunta 5    \label{q5}]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][Pregunta 6    \label{q6}]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}

\medskip
  \subfloat[][Pregunta 7    \label{q7}]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}

\caption{Diagramas de barras del test post-experimento}
\label{fig:q}
\end{adjustwidth}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(grey lines indicate page layout)

In the case, that you are satisfied with with the narrower images, you only need in ABove MWE remove `\adjustwidth` anviromant and set `Gin` norrower images. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.32\textwidth} % <---
  \centering
\subfloat[][Pregunta 1    \label{q1}]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfloat[][Pregunta 2    \label{q2}]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}\hfill
\subfloat[][Pregunta 3    \label{q2}]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}

\medskip
\subfloat[][Pregunta 4    \label{q4}]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subfloat[][Pregunta 5    \label{q5}]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}\hfill
\subfloat[][Pregunta 6    \label{q6}]{\includegraphics{example-image-c}}

\medskip
\subfloat[][Pregunta 7    \label{q7}]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}

\caption{Diagramas de barras del test post-experimento}
\label{fig:q}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you are changing the margins, it helps to put everything into one minipage or `\parbox` with the right width.  I used a `\parbox` since it doesn't change `\textwidth`.   Using `\rlap`, `\llap` and `\makebox` avoids overfull `\hbox` warnings.

I noticed that you stopped just short of the marginpar area, so that is where I started my `\llap`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \geometry{a4paper}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \hspace*{\fill}\rlap{\hspace{\dimexpr \marginparsep-4pt}% stop 4pt short of marginpar area
      \llap{\parbox{\dimexpr 1.05\textwidth+4em+1pt}{% set new margins plus 1pt roudoff
        \centering
        \makebox[0.35\textwidth]{\subfloat[Pregunta 1\label{q1}]{%
            \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}
        }}%
        \hspace{2em}%
        \makebox[0.35\textwidth]{\subfloat[Pregunta 2\label{q2}]{
            \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}
        }}%
        \hspace{2em}%
        \makebox[0.35\textwidth]{\subfloat[Pregunta 3\label{q3}]{
            \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}
        }}
        \par\medskip
% I was curious how this would work
        \subfloat[Pregunta 4\label{q4}]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}}\hfill
        \subfloat[Pregunta 5\label{q5}]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}}\hfill
        \subfloat[Pregunta 6\label{q6}]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}}\par\medskip

        \subfloat[Pregunta 7]{
            \label{q7}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}
            }
        \caption{Diagramas de barras del test post-experimento}
    }}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```